# How does Django handle form data coming from a table with multiple rows?

Tags: django, django-forms

For one of my Django projects, my HTML page contains a form which in turn contains a table. The structure of the form is as such:

```
<form name="bill" action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="id_date">Date </label>
            <input type="text" name="date" id="id_date" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="id_description">Description </label>
            <input id="id_description" type="text" name="description" maxlength="300" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="id_amount">Total Amount </label>
            <input type="text" name="amount" id="id_amount" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="id_debtors">Split Among </label>
            <table class="unequal_split">
                <thead>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Paid For</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 
                                <select name="people">
                                    <option value="xx">XX</option>
                                    <option value="yy">YY</option>                                        
                                    <option value="zz">ZZ</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select name="number_of_people">
                                    <option value="1">1 person</option>
                                    <option value="2">2 people</option>
                                    <option value="3">3 people</option>
                                    <option value="4">4 people</option>
                                    <option value="5">5 people</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="individual_amount" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>                        
        <li>
            <label for="save"></label>
            <button id="save" type="submit">Save</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

The table row that you see above repeats three times.

In `request.POST`, if I do a `getlist`, I can get the individual values but as you can see above, each row has one set of details which needs to be processed individually. So my question is, how exactly do I get this row level data in `views.py`?

Comment: Do you create the <input> and <select> field yourself? If yes, you don't do it the django way. Use the form library and ModelForm. Don't access request.POST, use form.cleaned_data.

Comment: How is this comment relevant to the question at hand? In any case, to answer your question, the first three list items are from the ModelForm and the last li concerned with the table has been created manually.

Comment: OK, you use ModelForm. Yes, it is relevant. Since you only can use form.cleaned_data if you use the form library. I added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you're saying that the fully rendered form has three different `select` inputs named `people`, three named `number_of_people`, and three named `individual_amount`.

There is a way in an HTTP POST to access a list of multiple values from an input, but it really only applies to `<select multiple="multiple">` or `<input type="checkbox">` or the like - i.e., multiple values from a single input rather than multiple with the same name..

What I would suggest, since you imply above that you're generating the table rows (as opposed to the above `<li>`s) in your view code rather than the ModelForm, is that instead of having `<select name="people">` three times you use `<select name="people_1">`, `<select name="people_2">`, etc.

Then in your view code you can access them as `request.POST['people_1']` and so on.

Comment: Thanks. Yes thats what I thought I would do as you can see in the comments in the other answer on this thread.

Answer (score 2):

The tables and how many the fields are embedded in the HTML has absolute *zero* to do with how those fields are accessed in Django (in any language for that matter).

Whatever the `name` attribute is, that is the key in `request.POST`. Simple as that.

Comment: So how exactly do I go about it? The form is supposed to send the data which could be as such: [ Date, Description, Amount, [ [XX, 1 person, 10], [YY, 3 people, 30], [ZZ, 1 person, 10] ] ]. How exactly do I access the last item (which in turn contains three other items/rows) which is coming from the table?

Comment: Once more: there's no embedded lists within lists. That's not how POST works. When you submit the form, a simple list of name/value pairs is sent. It doesn't matter what grouping or ordering you've implied via your HTML.

Comment: Right thanks. Got that bit about POST containing only simple name/value items. I suppose I'll have to somehow use formsets to go about it and maybe define the list items in the table as either another model or modify the model that I currently have.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use ModelForm, I guess that every HTML-row  has a corresponding DB-row. Create a ModelForm for every DB-row (model instance) and give it a prefix. Or you can use formsets. My advice: Never read from request.POST or request.GET, use form.cleaned_data.